# Avoid narrowing type conversion on function call

Tags: c++11

Suppose you want to avoid narrowing when calling a function

```
void foo(char c) { /* ... */ }

foo(4); // get a compilation error here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define your target function, and a forwarding template overload that will attempt a non-narrowing conversion to the target type (**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22490979bd1cbcaf)**):

```
void foo(char) {}
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& t) { foo(char{std::forward<T>(t)}); }

foo('a');
// foo(4);    // ill-formed
foo({4});
// foo(0);    // ill-formed
foo({0}); 
// foo(u'a'); // ill-formed
foo({u'a'});
int i = 2;
// foo(i);    // ill-formed
// foo({i});  // ill-formed
```

This has the nice advantage that clients can force the conversion themselves by passing a braced-init-list. Since the braced-init-list impedes template deduction, only the target function can be selected by overload resolution. So even though e.g. `foo(4)` matches the template overload and is ill-formed - since `int` cannot in general be converted to `char` without narrowing - `foo({4})` is well-formed since `4` can be converted to `char` without narrowing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class template on T that has

1) a template constructor on a different type X that tries to instantiate the class when the parameter is not T

2) a constructor with T as param that takes care of the case where you are instantiating the class with the exact type

```
#include <iostream>

// g++-4.9 -Werror=narrowing -std=c++11 main2.cc
// https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55783

template <typename T>
struct no_narrowing
{
    using type = T;

    // this template constructor lets you try to
    // instantiate a no_narrowing using a different
    // type. if Narrowing would take place 
    // value{ val } takes care of it
    template <typename X>
        no_narrowing(X val) : value{val} {}

    // if type is exactly T we use this
    no_narrowing(type val) : value{val} {}

    operator type() const { return value;}

    type value;
};

template <typename T>
using nn = no_narrowing<T>;


void print(nn<char> v)
{
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 2;

    print('d'); 
    print(i); // this will not compile

    return 0;
}
```